# specific select within sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table vbap : For all distinct POSNR, PARVW, I need to check if POSNR=POSNR2, if it's the case I select KUNNR. if POSNR<>POSNR2 and POSNR2 ='00000' I select KUNNR

[image]

Result:

[image]

I didn't understand how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems like just a `where` cause:

```
select t.*
from t
where POSNR2 in (POSNR, '00000')
```

Perhaps you are trying to prioritize the rows, to select one row per `kunnr`.  If so:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by parvw order by psnr2 desc) as seqnum
      from t
      where POSNR2 in (POSNR, '00000')
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: For the same [PARVW] I need to select POSNR2 = POSNR else POSNR2= '00000'.. the first query returns two results for POSNR = 000025:  0000515408 and 0000502356 .. I need to prioritize the case POSNR2 = POSNR

Comment: Make this `over (partition by vbeln, posnr, parvw order by posnr2 desc)`. (Or if you must be able to deal with negative numbers, too: `over (partition by vbeln, posnr, parvw order by case when posnr2 = posnr then 1 else 2 end)`.)

Comment: @ThorstenKettner exactly !!